# Strange deserialization exception

Tags: c#, json.net

I have 2 applications that share an assembly. 
The first serializes an object and sends it to the other to be deserialized for further processing.

This is what i get on the other end when attempting to deserialize the data ...

[image: Exception Details]

... Looking at the assemblies loaded in the watch window with "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()" I noticed the assembly in question is loaded in to the app domain but for some reason the Newtonsoft deserializer can't pick it up.

Any ideas where I should be looking for a solution to this?

Some other possibly relevant information ...

- Both applications are running on top of .Net Core 2.2
- The first app is a web api app.
- The second is an Azure Functions app.
- Because of the azure functions SDK i'm forced to use v11 of the newtonsoft lib.
- The object in question has been serialised with Json option ""

Further information requested form the comments ...

The actual message on the exception is:

```
Error resolving type specified in JSON 'Core.Objects.Workflow.Activities.Start`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], Core.Objects'. Path 'Activities[0].$type', line 1, position 285.
```

With a further inner exception reporting ....

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Core.Objects, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

At the point this exception occurs i'm inside FlowDefinition calling GetFlow() as defined below ...

```
public class FlowDefinition
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("App")]
    public int AppId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DefinitionJson { get; set; }

    public string ConfigJson { get; set; }

    [DontPrivilege]
    public Flow GetFlow() { return DefinitionJson != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Flow>(DefinitionJson, ObjectExtensions.JSONSettings) : null; }

    [DontPrivilege]
    public dynamic GetConfig() { return ConfigJson != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(ConfigJson, ObjectExtensions.JSONSettings) : null; }

    public virtual App App { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FlowInstanceData> Instances { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessProcessWorkflow> Processes { get; set; }
}

public class Flow

{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string RequiredRoles { get; set; }

    public Activity[] Activities { get; set; }

    public Link[] Links { get; set; }
}
```

... Activity is an abstract base type for all my activity types and cannot be directly deserialized instead a derived type must be seen.

And here's an example JSON string from the system that fails ...

```
{
   "Name":"Test",
   "RequiredRoles":"",
   "Links":[
      {
         "Source":"Start",
         "Destination":"53c102ac10ce109d7d62c489beb242ccb10a62d83",
         "Expression":"{destination}.Item = {source}.Data.Message"
      }
   ],
   "Activities":[
      {
         "$type":"Core.Objects.Workflow.Activities.Start`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]], Core.Objects",
         "Ref":"Start",
         "AuthToken":null,
         "Data":null,
         "State":null,
         "Previous":null,
         "Next":null,
         "AssignValues":null
      },
      {
         "$type":"Core.Objects.Workflow.Activities.DebugActivity, Core.Objets, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
         "Ref":"53c102ac10ce109d7d62c489beb242ccb10a62d83",
         "Item":null,
         "State":null,
         "Previous":null,
         "Next":null,
         "AssignValues":null,
         "Data":null
      }
   ]
}
```

... all types shown above are defined in the same assembly and compiled as a .Net Standard 2.0 assembly that is being consumed by a .Net Core 2.2 Azure functions app.

Comment: Can you add the smallest amount of code of the object being serialized for witch the error occours? Also writing down the string of the error can help other users.

Comment: Please don't show a picture of the error message. The error message is text, so you can include it directly in the question instead of a picture of the text. Also, if someone a year from now has the same error and searches Google, the words in the picture won't be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you are using objects with constructor/dependencies containing object that cannot be deserialized because of missing dependencies.

Also check if it's correct that the type contains something called Core.**Objets** and not Core.**Objects**.